# GSON from JSON nested object null pointer exception

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception, gson

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
   “weight": {
      "type": "weight",
      "range": [
         "2016-02-15",
         "2016-02-16",
         "2016-02-17",
         "2016-02-18",
         "2016-02-19",
         "2016-02-20",
         "2016-02-21"
      ],
      "days": [
         {
            "weight": [
               {
                  "bmi": 29.5,
                  "date": "2016-02-14",
                  "logId": 1455494399000,
                  "source": "API",
                  "time": "23:59:59",
                  "weight": 90.3
               },
      ]
}
```

I then have the following classes that I want this JSON to be added to.

```
public class fitbitTypeWeight {
    public fitbitDays weight;
}

public class fitbitDays {
    public fitbitDayWeight days;
}

public class fitbitDayWeight {
    public fitbitWeight weight;
}

public class fitbitDayWeight {
    public fitbitWeight weight;
}
```

Then, I have the following code to try and parse it.

```
public static void readJSON() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();  
    type = gson.fromJson(file, fitbitTypeWeight.class);
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    gson = builder.create();
    createFitBitInfo();
}

private static void createFitBitInfo() throws ITrustException{
    RemoteMonitoringDAO db = new RemoteMonitoringDAO(prodDAO);
    RemoteMonitoringDataBean temp=new RemoteMonitoringDataBean();
    fitbitDayWeight info = type.weight.days;
    temp.setFitbitWeight(info.weight.weight);
    temp.setFitbitDate(info.weight.date);
    temp.setLoggedInMID(userID);
    db.storeFitbitData(temp);
}
```

However, I am getting a NPE exception on fitbitDayWeight info = type.weight.days;

Any suggestions on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is malformed. Looking just at the `days` element, we have:

```
"days": [
  {
    "weight": [
      {
        "bmi": 29.5,
        "date": "2016-02-14",
        "logId": 1455494399000,
        "source": "API",
        "time": "23:59:59",
        "weight": 90.3
      },
]
```

Looking at that, you've got:

- dangling `,` on list `weight`
- no closing `]` on list `weight`
- no closing `}` on `0` in list `days`

(To be complete, the if the final `,` were not there, `]` would close `weight` then `}` would close object `0` in list `days`, leaving `days` and base unclosed.)

Also, you have a `“` as your first quote instead of `"`. I don't know for sure if GSON is ok with angle quotes, but I know the JSON standard asks for `"` on all quotes.

I'm honestly slightly surprised GSON doesn't spit errors on load because of this. But the reason you're getting a NullPointerException is because `type.weight.days` is set to the default value because GSON couldn't read a value for it.